# C++ Operator Overloading : Multiplication of User Defined Type by floating point values

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-operators

I am trying to implement multiplication operators (`operator*`) for 4 situations.

Imagine I have a `class rain`.

```
namespace manchester {

    namespace manchester_private_dont_use_this {

        template<typename T>
        class rain
        {

        public:
            rain(T initial_rain)
                : m_rain(initial_rain)
            {
            }

        private:
             T m_quantity_of_rain;
        };

    }

} //namespace manchester
```

Assume this class is declared inside a private namespace. `typedef rain<float> rainf;` and `typedef rain<double> raind` expose the functionality of this class inside a non-private namespace. By private namespace I mean another nested namespace which is called something like `namespace rainprivate_do_not_use_me`. (In the example I actually added two namespaces to explain what I'm talking about, but that's not really important.) That's the best I could come up with to prevent the end user (me) from trying to create a `rain<int>` which doesn't make much sense, since rain is measured in litres., and therefore we can have non-integer quantities.

Anyway, I was to implement `operator*` like I said, for the case of multiplying a quantity of rain by both a `float` and a `double`. Am I correct in assuming  that since these types can be implicitly converted, I only need to implement an operator where the rhs variable is a `double` and where the lhs variable is a `double`. (By double I actually mean the type, T.)

Again, I am guessing here - see my previous question about unary operators, but I guess something like this: (Again I couldn't find any info on SO to answer my question.)

```
// friend function:
inline rain<T> operator*(const rain<T>& _rain, const T _t)
{
    return rain<T>(_rain.m_quantity_of_rain * _t);
}

inline rain<T> operator*(const T _t, const rain<T>& _rain)
{
    return rain<T>(_rain.m_quantity_of_rain * _t);
}
```

Again, I was unsure so thought its probably better to ask than learn it wrong. The 4 situations I was thinking of was the two above, and then the two hidden cases for when `float` may be converted to double`in the case when`T`is type`double`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You could use directly double, and let the implicit converson do the task, but note that since float are smaller in size than double, this may cause a loss of data.

```
inline rain<T> operator*(const rain<T>& _rain, const double _t)
{
    return rain<T>(_rain.m_quantity_of_rain * _t);
}

inline rain<T> operator*(const double _t, const rain<T>& _rain)
{
    return rain<T>(_rain.m_quantity_of_rain * _t);
}
```

also with your attempt to avoid the specific template instantiation, like `rain<int>` you could throw a compilation error when somebody try to do that. Please refer here: [How to intentionally cause a compile-time error on template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926637/how-to-intentionally-cause-a-compile-time-error-on-template-instantiation)

Comment: Okay thanks, I will take a look at throwing a compiler error like you suggested. In the example you just gave you said that specifically using double may cause loss of data? Which are you suggesting then, use the example you gave or the one I gave?

Comment: The loss of data will happens in the case you have rain<float> and a real double as the second parameter. That is in your example and in mine, but in the example that I gave you still have the double inside the function, and could do something if you want to avoid the lossless of data, in your example, the lossless happens in the call of the function itself.

Comment: Ah right I see. I'd suggest sticking with my example then because since the user has to chose between using the template types of float and double one would assume they would do all arithmetic with the same types as chosen for the template. (I would assume anyway!)