# Make C++ fail compilation on specific instantiation of template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization

I'm working on a project which has an template function as so:

```
template <class T> 
T foo<T>(T val) { return someFunc(val); }

template <>
bool foo<bool>(bool val) { return otherFunc(val); };
```

Now, I have a class `Bar`, which I don't want to accept as input.  In fact, I want it to generate an easy to spot compile error.   The problem is that if I do this:

```
template <>
Bar foo<Bar>(Bar val) { static_assert(false,"uh oh..."); }
```

It fails on every compile.  I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/3926854/7673414, which says that I need to make reference to the template type, otherwise the static assert always takes place.   The problem is I don't have a template type here.   If I do:

```
template< typename T >
struct always_false { 
    enum { value = false };  
};

template <>
Bar foo<Bar>(Bar val) { static_assert(always_false<Bar>::value,"uh oh..."); }
```

then it also always fails compiling.   Is there a way to ensure that an instantiation of the template with type `Bar` always causes a compile error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since `foo` is a complete specialization, it will always get compiled, and the static assert will always get called.

However, there’s an [easier way](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions):

```
template <>
Bar foo<Bar>(Bar val) = delete;
```

This will say that this specific version is deleted, and cannot be called.

Comment: That's nice but I'd delete the d-tor instead of having to delete all the various c-tors.

Comment: @YehezkelB. This is a function template, not a class template. You can delete function template specializations, not just constructors and destructors.

Answer (score 3):

Another way is enable the template (not specialized version) only if the type is different from `Bar`

```
template <class T> 
typename std::enable_if< ! std::is_same<T, Bar>::value, T>::type foo<T>(T val)
 { return someFunc(val); }
```

If you can use C++14, is can be simplified using `std::enable_if_t`

```
template <class T> 
std::enable_if_t< ! std::is_same<T, Bar>::value, T> foo<T>(T val)
 { return someFunc(val); }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::is_same`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_same) to help with your requirement.

```
template <class T> 
T foo<T>(T val)
{
   // Make sure T is not Bar
   static_assert(std::is_same<T, Bar>::value == false, "uh oh...");
   return someFunc(val);
}
```

Comment: Would you please add the missing `)` for `static_assert`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using c++17, you can put everything together with `constexpr if`:

```
template< typename T >
auto foo( T val )
{
    static_assert( !std::is_same_v<T,Bar> );

    if constexpr( std::is_same_v<T,bool> )
    {
        return  other_func( val );
    }
    else
    {
        return some_func( val );
    }

}
```

Then you can `static_assert` at the first line, without the pain of compilation failure of the template specific instantiation.

A live example is available at https://wandbox.org/permlink/PpR6G0gcvMRoxhhZ