# make compilation fail on specific instantiation of template class

Tags: c++, class, templates, compiler-errors

[Make C++ fail compilation on specific instantiation of template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701567/make-c-fail-compilation-on-specific-instantiation-of-template-function) explains how to make compilation to fail if a function is instantiated with a specific class, but not how to do so with a class.

Say I have a class :

```
template<class T>
class foo;
```

And another `class Bar`. How would I make compilation fail if foo is instantiated or specialized with `Bar`?

All solutions are like run-time (even though evaluation is at compile time the error can only be given at run- time which is not suitable).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want an hard compilation error when `foo<Bar>` is instantiated, you can use `static_assert` (which also allows you to provide a custom error message):

```
template <class T>
class foo
{
    static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T, Bar>,
        "foo does not support Bar");
};
```

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/25R4doTnZSk03gOd)

Answer (score 1):

Put a static_assert(false, "Class cannot be instantiated with xxx"); in the bad specialization.

```
struct foo { };
template<typename T>
struct bar_base {
 ...
};
template<typename T>
struct foo : foo_base<T>
{ };
template<>
struct bar<foo>
{
  static_assert(false, "bar cannot be instantiated with foo");
};
```

Here bar_base holds all the actual implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
template<class T>
class foo {};

struct bar {};

template <>
class foo<bar>;
```

This declares a specialization for `bar` but doesn't define it, so anything that tries to cause instantiation will fail. Just make sure to declare this specialization in the same header file as the primary definition of `foo`, so that it's not possible for a translation unit to see the primary definition but not the specialization.